# GCC C++ Linker section on FC13

Tags: eclipse, opengl, binary, include-path, freeglut

I am trying to get OpenGL and Glut running on Eclipse Linux FC13.

After spending two days on it, I admit that help is needed. On FC13 Eclipse, I see
`/usr/include/GL` and `/usr/include/SDL` -- so the libs are there. I started Eclipse, and then tried to run a simple program on it, just like suggested [here](http://www.ferdychristant.com/blog/articles/DOMM-72MPPE). However, two things were missing in those steps:

1. Callisto could not be installed --
   nothing was found from the
   repository
2. GCC C++ Linker is not found anywhere
   for Eclipse 3.5.2.

When trying to run the program, I see this error:

> Program does not exist

and sometimes

> Binary not found

If I just run the "hello world" it works, but otherwise, those errors happen every time I try to include glut gl or sdl commands.

Here is an excerpt from the compiler error:

```
make all 
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0   -c -o tw.o tw.cpp
tw.cpp: In function ‘void main_loop_function()’:
g++ -o tw tw.o
```

Yes, apparently the compiler is not able to see the glu, gl, sdl and glut libraries.

Some suggestion on how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler that your program uses additional libraries.

Use the -l argument

```
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0  -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lX11  -c -o tw.o tw.cpp
```

This should help against unsatisfied link errors.

You can set these in the properties of your Project.
Properties->c/c++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->Linker

Comment: Thanks. now the linker has the lib. Nice.

Comment: Here is what it shows now:
    make all 
    Building target: zdt4
    Invoking: GCC C Linker
    gcc -LGL -LSDL -Lglut -o"zdt4"  ./zdt4.o

then.. it is down to one error message:

    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [zdt4] Error 1

and a lot of message like this
    undefined reference to `glClear'
    undefined reference to `glViewport'
    undefined reference to `glutInit'

some suggestion?

Comment: that error message is gone - undefined reference to `glViewport'! nice. now just left this awkward message:
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘key’
this declared in the top of the program as "bool key[321];". any idea?

Comment: @ThreaderSlash your sourcefile ends with .c instead of .cpp so gcc will try to compile it as c source, c does not have the bool type. rename your source file to end with .cpp

Comment: at c++ project option, it doesn't have the option Properties->c/c++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->Linker, therefore, it gives you error once you cann't setup the libs SDL, GLUT, GL. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the compiler is able to find the appropriate header files or not. If not, you are sure to get compiler errors. Try using the `-I` option to set the appropriate paths.

Once you've fixed that, check if there are any linker errors (undefined symbols/references or the sort). If you do: Try to set the library paths using the `-L` option and ask the compiler to link in the specific libraries by using the `-l` option. Note that the latter expects something like `-lmath` where in reality the library being linked in is actually called `libmath.so` or `libmath.a` (as the case may be).